# How to create a regex which captures the IP addresses followed by a value associated with that IP address?

Tags: php, regex, extract, ip-address

I am running a scripted job on a set of nodes, the log associated with that job is providing me with the data string I am trying to parse with a regex. I try to extract the IP  address of all nodes that have a success rate of 0% so from my link here https://regex101.com/r/jX9hW8/2 . What I am trying to get as out put would be

```
10.0.0.183
Success rate is 0 percent
```

I would be here all day if I tried to list everything I've tried, but it seems that all I am picking up is any numbers that are in a bracket.

Comment: [`'~^\s*D\d+\.node\s+\(([\d.]+)\):(?:(?!^\s*(?:D\d+\.node|Success rate is )\s).)*^\s*Success rate is 0\b~ms'`](https://regex101.com/r/bP0aI9/1)?

Comment: Please try to improve your spelling. Although high level English is not expected here, but you can get much better acceptance if you follow this [six simple spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh/291370#291370).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks Wiktor for your input. That regex looks a lot more complex than the one I was using! It'll take me a while to work my way through it. Appreciate the answer.

Comment: So, does it work? I actually made one costly mistake: it should be [`^\s*D\d+\.node\s+\(([\d.]+)\):(?:(?!^\s*(?:D\d+\.node|Success rate is)\s).)*^\s*Success rate is 0\b`](https://regex101.com/r/bP0aI9/2)

Comment: @peterh I don't understand where my spelling mistakes are? Could you enlighten me?

Comment: @peterh Didn't think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
'~^\s*D\d+\.node\s+\(([\d.]+)\):(?:(?!^\s*(?:D\d+\.node|Success rate is)\s).)*^\s*Success rate is 0\b~ms'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bP0aI9/2)

The idea is to use a tempered greedy token that matches any text other than the leading and trailing delimiters.

- `^\s*D\d+\.node\s+\(([\d.]+)\):` - the leading delimiter, matching:

  - `^` - the start of a line
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `D` - a literal `D`
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `\.node` -  aliteral string `.node`
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `\(`  - a `(`
  - `([\d.]+)` - Group 1 matching 1+ digits or literal dots
  - `\):` - a literal `):`
- `^\s*Success rate is 0\b` - the trailing delimiter matching

  - `^` - start of a line
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `Success rate is 0\b` - a character sequence `Success rate is 0` matched as a whole word  (`\b` prevents matching `03`, e.g.)

The `(?:(?!^\s*(?:D\d+\.node|Success rate is)\s).)*` is the tempered greedy token that matches any character (`.` will match any character) that is not a starting character of the following sequences:
 - `^\s*` - start of line followed with 0+ whitespaces
 - `(?:D\d+\.node` - either `D` followed with 1+ digits followed with `.node`
 - `|` - or
 - `Success rate is)` - literal string `Success rate is`
 - `\s` -  a whitespace

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew this worked like a charm, and I learned a lot from your regex! Much appreciated